# Refresh class instance variable that is set with ||=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a model instance variable in which I keep descriptions that will be "mostly" static throughout the application.

The code looks like this

```
def self.get_lastname(client_id)
  @client_by_lastname ||= Client.select(:id, :lastname)
  .map{|e| e.attributes.values}
  .inject({}){|memo, client| memo[client[0]] = client[1]; memo}
  return @client_by_lastname[client_id] if @client_by_lastname[client_id]

  result = Client.select('lastname').where('id = ?',client_id)
  return @client_by_lastname[client_id] = result[0].lastname 
end
```

So essentially. On first load it stores the clients and their last names in an array. However a client "May" change last name every once in a while when a client is bought by another entity. The client ID remains the same but the first name and last name will change. When that happens, this client last name ends up being wrong in the app and we essentially have to restart the app for the instance variable to be reset.

There has to be a way to reset these instance variables so that they are reloaded the next time they are queried. I would then place an after_save callback on the client file when the first name or last name is modified and get that instance variable reloaded.

How can one go about "refreshing" the instance variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can one go about "refreshing" the instance variable?

Simply set it to `nil`. Then, upon next call, it'll be reloaded from the db.

Or you could proactively replace the value yourself. First, separate memoization and computation.

```
def self.get_lastname(client_id)
  @client_by_lastname ||= compute_client_by_last_name

end

def compute_client_by_last_name
  Client.select(:id, :lastname)
      .map{|e| e.attributes.values}
      .inject({}){|memo, client| memo[client[0]] = client[1]; memo}
end
```

Then, when you want to refresh the state (in an after_save callback or wherever)

```
@client_by_lastname = compute_client_by_last_name
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect it to be that simple.